# Does ipad (ibooks) supports mixed layout epubs (reflowable with some fixed pages)

Tags: epub, apple-books, fixed-layout

I want few pages in my reflowable epub (pages having complex tables which span to two pages in PDF) as fixed layout. As per IDPF standard, I have added rendition property for those pages in spine as pre-paginated and spread as landscape. It works fine in Readium and Vital source but not in ipad (ibooks).

Is it possible to do so in ibooks?

Also, ibooks does not support  `.... rendition:spread>landscape</meta>`